# Starting up iPhone XR with jammed power button

Tags: iphone

My iPhone XR has a jammed power button (due to a pretty rough fall a few days ago while I was biking). The power button is physically stuck in the phone, so, for example, I can't manually lock my phone anymore, I have to wait until 30 seconds pass and the iPhone itself automatically dims the screen and locks the phone.

This also means that if I long press just the top volume button, I get the same result as if I were pressing both the top volume button *and* the power button on a perfectly functional iPhone, i.e. the screen with the "slide to power off" and "SOS emergency call" options show up. It seems like the power button is effectively pressed down all the time now.

Naturally, I have a few concerns:

1. If I have to shut down my iPhone at some point, will I be able to turn it back on by just pressing the top volume button? Or will the iPhone "reset" the power button upon shutting down, i.e. will it suddenly consider it not pressed when its physical position has not changed?
2. Is there any risk of the power button "reset" described in (1) suddenly happening one day, seemingly unprompted? Could the power button wear out?
3. Are there alternative ways of starting up the iPhone from a state of being shut down, without using any buttons?
4. Any ways to fix the power button itself? A few Google searches tells me that it's hard to manually repair a power button because of its arrangement within the iPhone. My efforts to un-jam the power button have also been fruitless. Furthermore it seems like the shell of the phone has warped/dented a little around the power button, so I doubt I could un-jam this button, at least on my own. Does Apple offer repair services for such things? Would it even be possible given the warping?

Comment: If you have *physically damaged* the power button the answers to numbers 1, 2 & 3 are "maybe." I would ask around locally about phone repair shops. I had one in Austin (TX) near me that did good work and could have likely fixed that issue. There might be one of those near you.